# How to write code for update status (like twitter) on web application?

Tags: html, ajax, web-applications, twitter

I would like to create a web application which receive status(text) from android. The language that I think to use are Ajax and html. So I would like to know how to update status on web page, though I don't want to use Twitter API 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/book.html#N21AF0) is a good tutorial on making a twitter app using HTML and Ajax. The tutorial uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)(a JavaScript library) which doesn't take too long to get started with.

In case you don't know, Ajax is not a language but a methodology. You need to use JavaScript (or a JavaScript library) to do Ajax.